# Multilanguage document in Latex

Tags: latex, internationalization

how do you prepare Latex document with a translation... I need 1 multilanguage document. It should be something like:

```
\section{pl:Costam; en:Something}
```

Then I'd like to render it in Polish or English...

Comment: There are the [`translations`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations) package and the [`translator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package (part of the `beamer` bundle) that may or may not be helpful for the task at hand

Comment: There's a similar question in the tex.stackexchange with some helpful answers.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60781/235101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution!

```
\newboolean{eng}
\setboolean{eng}{false}
\newboolean{pol}
\setboolean{pol}{true}
\newboolean{rus}
\setboolean{rus}{false}

\newcommand{\lang}[3]
{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{eng}}{#1}{}\ifthenelse{\boolean{pol}}{#2}{}\ifthenelse{\boolean{ger}}{#3}{}
}
```

Usage:

```
\lang{English}{Polski}{Deutch}
```

Comment: This answer a) misses the information where `\newboolean` and `\ifthenelse` are defined and b) introduces _two spurious spaces_ in the definition of `\lang`.

Answer (score 15):

If all else fails, you can go for an even more basic, almost insultingly dumb approach:

```
\newcommand{\dumblang}[2]{{#1}}
```

This defines a command with two arguments (`[2]`) and spits out the first (`{#1}`).

So for example you can have...

```
\usepackage[\dumblang{english}{italian}]{babel}

%snip

\section{\dumblang{Introduction}{Introduzione}}
\dumblang{Your introduction goes here!}{Scrivi qua la tua introduzione!}
```

...and when you want the document in Italian, you can just change `\dumblang` to:

```
\newcommand{\dumblang}[2]{{#2}}
```

Comment: Simple and genius.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, you might want to consider the solutions proposed at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/whether-its-possible-to-keep-translation-together-with-original-text

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the [`parallel` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel)? Check the [docs (PDF link)](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel/parallel.pdf) to see if it is appropriate for your needs.

You can see some other options by [searching CTAN for "parallel text"](http://www.ctan.org/cgi-bin/search.py?metadataSearch=parallel+text&metadataSearchSubmit=Search) (I didn't have a lot of luck with "multiple languages" and "translation").

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using conditionals, e.g. a `\ifdef`s.  With appropriate macros this need not be utterly horrible to read.

Much better would be use a localisation tool, such a an XLIFF editor.  Take a look at [the XLIFF tools page](http://xliff-tools.freedesktop.org/wiki/Resources/).  The great strength of going this route is the XLIFF slots directly into standard translators tools like translation memory.